# Does PhoneGap have a video player?

Tags: cordova

I noticed PhoneGap has an audio player and recorder, but I was wondering if it has a way to play video?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't have. But plugins are available to use.

I just did using the below one

[Phonegap - video plugin - github](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/VideoPlayer)

[Phonegap - video Plugin - Simon-blog](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.in/2011/11/video-player-plugin-for-phonegap.html)

Answer (score 3):

PhoneGap uses HTML5, so, it supports the [video tag.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

Comment: which is OK for distant video but seems to be buggy with local video files :(

Answer (score 1):

There are many threads about this issue. Someone advising to use aVideo plugin. But works not normally on PhoneGap 1.0.0. So I'm making small changes to make it work. [There is a result](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25585776/VideoTest.zip) with example.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use HTML5  tag to play local videos on the phone, so you should use a plugin instead. I implemented previously a plugin for this and I will update README soon but it is typical Phonegap Plugin.

[Phonegap Video Player](https://github.com/adnanbasar/PhoneGap-Video-Player-Plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the

```
<video></video>
```

HTML5 tag.

Comment: depending on the version of Android, <video will not play..I am using a kindle fire, and it shows a video player but does not play.